# Update cellEditorParams after table creation

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I'm using ag grid to display a table using Vue.js. I have a column definition like this:

```
        {
          headerName: "Status",
          field: "featureStatus",
          width: 110,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: "agSelectCellEditor ",
          cellEditorParams: {
            values: []
          }
        },
```

this.allFeatureStatusNames is a computed variable that returns a array of strings:

```
 allFeatureStatusNames: function() {
      return this.allFeatureStatuses.map(status => status.name)
    }
```

I have a watcher on allFeatureStatuses that I would like to update the cellEditorParams after the table have been created:

```
    allFeatureStatuses: function() {
      let colDef = this.columnDefs.find(col => col.headerName == "Status")

      if (colDef) {
        colDef.cellEditorParams = {
          values: this.allFeatureStatusNames
        }
      }

      this.gridColumnApi.refreshCells()
    },
```

The problem I have is that the cell editor is never updated. It's always empty. How do I refresh or update cellEditorParams after the tabel have been created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although with your approach, the issue may be that your colDef object is not getting updated because you are trying to modify an existing object and creating a new colDef may work for you.

Something like below has worked for me -

```
cellEditorParams: this.getValues.bind(this);

getValues: function() {
   let allowedVals = this.allFeatureStatusNames;
   return { values : allowedVals};
}
```